# On Django, cookie is assigned outside the boundary of string

Tags: jquery, django

I tried to use both `document.cookie` and `$.cookie("productId",productId)` on javascript/jquery, but it seems like the assignment goes out of its boundaries.

When I **run document.cookie command in Chrome**, I am expecting to get:

```
"csrftoken=bh1n0k3sBKjXQtClAOwwT5DPgN22Dxqh; productId=2;"
```

But instead, I get:

```
"csrftoken=bh1n0k3sBKjXQtClAOwwT5DPgN22Dxqh; productId=; 2"
```

I'm not sure if it's because of **csrftoken** has been already assigned. The problem is, what is happening, and how do I assign productId properly?

Answer (score 0):

I did not put in the imported js file, but instead, I just assigned it on the html onclick attribute as:

```
onclick='document.cookie="productId={{ product.id }}"';
```